# How does glmnet put constraints on coefficient upper and lower bounds?

Tags: optimization, lasso, regularization, glmnet, constraint

Based on *glmnet* documentation at [https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html)

Coefficient upper and lower bounds
These are recently added features that enhance the scope of the models. Suppose we want to fit our model, but limit the coefficients to be bigger than -0.7 and less than 0.5. This is easily achieved via the upper.limits and lower.limits arguments:

```
tfit=glmnet(x,y,lower=-.7,upper=.5)
plot(tfit)
```

I was wondering what optimization techniques they are using and whether there is a reference paper.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

GLmnet is based on Newton's method. The boundary conditions are used as hard thresholds in the update equations:

See the [source code](https://github.com/cran/glmnet/blob/e85bab25e05c0d33095d71dcd114328ca25128eb/src/glmnetpp/include/glmnetpp_bits/elnet_point/internal/base.hpp#LL49C5-L69) (currently, mostly C++):

```
static void 
update_beta(
        value_t& a, 
        value_t gk, 
        value_t x_var,
        value_t penalty,
        value_t a_min,
        value_t a_max,
        value_t l1_regul, 
        value_t l2_regul) {
    auto a_copy = a; 
    auto u = gk + a_copy * x_var; 
    auto v = std::abs(u) - penalty * l1_regul; 
    a = 0.0;
    if (v > 0.0) {
        a = std::max(a_min,
                std::min(a_max,
                    std::copysign(v,u) / (x_var + penalty * l2_regul)) );
    }
}
```